# Integerating SAP acquired software into the SAP ecosystem

Tags: abap

Given that SAP software is written in SAP ABAP, while the other technologies are written primarily in Java or .NET.

Also in certain industries, SAP partners with other companies using their software above the SAP Netweaver environment. SAP fills the deficiency in areas where it does not have a solution by using third party software in addition to it's own homegrown ABAP solution.

With the growing number of software SAP acquires each year does it mean SAP technical team has to know Java/.NET in addition to ABAP to work on such technologies? or is it that SAP projects recruit Java, .NET and ABAPers on such project.

```
59  Concur Technologies Sept 2014 Travel and Expense Management USA   $8.3b
58  SeeWhy          May 2014        Behavioral target marketing USA   $1.1b
57  Fieldglass      Mar 2014        Contingent labor and servicesUSA    
56  KXEN            Oct 2013        Predictive analytics        France  
55  hybris          May 2013        E-Commerce Solutions        Switzerland 
54  Camilion        March 2013      Insurance solutions         Canada  
53  SmartOps        Feb 2013        Inventory optimization      USA 
52  Ticket-Web      Feb 2013        CRM for sports and entertainUSA 
51  Ariba           Oct 2012        Supplier network            USA   $4.3b
50  Syclo           Jun 2012        Mobile asset management     USA 
49  datango         Jan 2012        Electronic performance      Germany 
48  SuccessFactors  Dec 2011        Talent Management           USA   $3.4b
47  Right HemisphereSep 2011        3D visualization            USA 
46  Crossgate       Sep 2011        B2B eCommerce               Germany 
45  Secude          Mar 2011        Security software Germany   
44  Cundus          Dec 2010        Disclosure Management       Germany 
43  Sybase          May 2010        Database, middleware,       USA   $5.8b
42  TechniData      May 2010        Environmental, Health       Germany 
41  SAF             Sep 2009        Inventory Management        Switzer$91m
40  Highdeal        May 2009        High-volume billing         France  
39  Visiprise       Jul 2008        Manufacturing Execution     USA 
38  Saicon INC      Oct 2014        US Recruitment              India   
37  Business ObjectsOct 2007        Business Intelligence       France$6.78b
36  Yasu TechnologiesOct 2007       Business Rules Management   India   
35  Wincom CommunicatMay 2007       Internet Communication soft USA 
34  MaXware         May 2007        Identity software           Norway  
33  Outlooksoft     May 2007        Planning & consolidation    USA
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about recruiting and personal education/development advice.

Comment: My apologies. Does it mean i should edit the tag. I am not clear where else should i post a SAP related question.

Comment: Also voting to close the question. The SAP Developer Network is a good place for such a question.

Comment: Thanks Gerd Castan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always valuable to know other technologies besides ABAP because as you said some SAP functionality is limited. There will be some problems that can't be solved with pure ABAP and must need to use a third party executable file for example a connection to a legacy proxy that is not compatible with ABAP and the vendor can't provide one that fulfills SAP requirements, in that case you'll need to code a program that should be executed by SAP with some OS permissions.

In my experience, technologies that involve ABAP+another language would be PI(or XI in older versions)